# How do I avoid all deferred scripts being evaluated and compiled in one single task causing a long task on the main thread?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, web, browser

It seems that using defer on scripts causes all of these scripts to be evaluated compiled and executed at once meaning in one single task before the DOMContentLoaded event.

This means if you or I have in my case a few of these scripts that are fairly slow to be executed, the task can become long and degrade the performance and Core Web Vitals of the page.

Most of these script depend on each other or at least should be executed in order, that's why the goto strategy was to use defer but I didn't know about the result of them being executed in a single task.

My plan is to insert some of them with JS when the DOMContentLoaded is fired, but this means that unless I preload them, they'll start to be downloaded much later. The end result is different than simply using defer.

Is there any way of breaking up that one long task or avoiding all of the deferred scripts being 'done' in one task?

Comment: Remove `defer` and include them right before </body>, in the correct order. The scripts will load and run in sequence.

Comment: @ChrisG That actually sounds really simple and reasonable, I am so caught up in all the 'better' way to load the scripts I forgot the basics :) thanks for the advice, I'll try this way

Comment: I think you should have one entry point only. JS is anyway single threaded so it's not a matter of having too many tasks all at once. The sum of all will remain the same. The problem is the order of execution in case those js contain code that will run beyond pure definitions only. So you should have one entry point and that's usually your page calling the api imported

Comment: It's always best to call for these scripts after window load. That way you can get your html painted immediately but such is not always possible right but playing with the state of when it loads is ideal to meet your needed solution.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Thanks. I am not sure what you mean by "So you should have one entry point and that's usually your page calling the api imported" Could you please clarify? :)

Comment: @BGPHiJACK You have a good point in that if I know the scripts take long I should not delay the HTML / DOM. I don't however like to rely on window.load since that can sometimes take fairly long.

Comment: I said something that could be considered wrong... but it makes your life simpler. I meant that my js files usually contain definitions only (functions mostly) and my page including them will invoke those functions. So my entry point will be the global scope in my page. By the way ...  Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating. Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document.

Comment: That's from MDN doc. so you can still use defer and yet use the DOMContentLoaded event to run your page entry point. My entry point argument was a bit flawed because even a function definition is actually assigning a function object to a variable in that scope. But it's not code running out of control

Comment: Well I'd open console and check round-trip, the load state occurs when all items downloaded are ready but if there's many scripts awaiting to run and slow's down body load yeah sure, that onload check would be slow but it's most effective way to not leave a white-page till CSS/JS/etc can all finally load and paint to page.

Comment: If you can determine the script that's running and slowing body from completing as it'd obviously would start as soon as it's retrieved. You can delay this script or incorporate it differently.

Comment: In production environments it's common to bundle all the scripts together.  So the premise of the question is kind of a moot point.

Comment: @Yogi Of course that's valid and I'll keep that in mind as a solution, but I am also wondering if this 'execution' of all deferred scripts in one task is intended and if so if it's possible to avoid a long task by lets say breaking up the tasks in 2 :)